# Installing ruby lobste.rs app on hosting, what lobsters$ supposed to do?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hosting

So, this is my first time installing ruby on the rails app on the hosting, here is the guide: https://github.com/jcs/lobsters

So, I did clone it and then changed to directory lobsters

Now, what does lobsters$ command supposed to do? is it command at all? when I simply type it in, it replays with "Command not found" ?

Help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`lobsters$` it is not a command. It's just a directory name.

```
$ git clone git://github.com/jcs/lobsters.git
  ^^^^^^^^^ # clone repository to the `lobster` directory
$ cd lobsters
  ^^^^^^^^^^^ # go to the `lobster` directory.
lobsters$ 
^^^^^^^^^ # current directory
```